# SSRS select words from string with unknown lengths and begin point

Tags: reporting-services, substring, trim

I am trying to retrieve words from a Field Value. This is what the field value looks likes:

```
<li data-val="1469" data-id="1404">Explanation of P2P and Non-P2P Processes<img onclick="removeMultiValItem(event)" src="images/delete.gif" width="19" height="19"></li>
```

I would like to print the words between the first '>' and the next '<'

The next trick is that it also pulls 2 codes like:

```
<li data-id="1404" data-val="1474">iProcurement (how to place orders);<img style="" onclick="removeMultiValItem(event)" src="images/delete.gif"></li><li data-id="1404" data-val="1471">How to GRV<img style="" onclick="removeMultiValItem(event)" src="i
```

In this case what I want to see is iProcurment (how to place orders); How to GRV

TIA

Comment: In both examples the values you need to show are between <li...>value<img>.  Is this the structure of all your values?

Comment: Yes. I was able to get the first value but I cannot get the remaining values. The number of values is undefined, could be 3 or 5 at different rows

Comment: Adding to elaborate about the value: there could be 3 values on one row and the next row has 5 values. E.g. row1 = ...<li...>value<img...>...<li...>value<img...>...<li...>value<img...>... row2 = ...<li...>value<img...>...<li...>value<img...>...<li...>value<img...>...<li...>value<img...>...<li...>value<img...>... I want the values separated by ;